# "Backdoor-list.txt" files unexpectedly in server

Tags: permissions, ftp, troubleshooting

[image: backdoor-list files]

Furthermore, there are "bad-directory-permissions-list.... .txt"files.

My website is currently under repair due to malicious code being found.  Could this be part of it?  Should I delete these files as well?

Answer (score 1):

If somebody is actively looking into your site to hunt malware, let them do the repairs first before you delete anything.

Those numbers look like timestamps, so my guess is that those are results from malware-scans running at those dates. It's a text-file, you can download them and take a look at the content. Maybe add an (anonymized) example content to your question. Also, add information about your hosting company, because that's most likely a custom configuration they are running.

Lastly: when in doubt, contact your host.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to give me this advice, especially since its such a newb question!!

Comment: You're welcome! We all have to start at some point, and it's by no means obvious. Dealing with an infected site is stressful enough, I very much understand that you'd want to make extra sure this isn't part of the problem.